# What could be causing High HC GPM, CO GPM, prevent the RPM from going over 4000, and creating an odd exhaust sound?

Tags: toyota, exhaust, camry, power, emissions

I have a Toyota Camry 94, it failed its emission test today with 2.62 HC GPM(Limit is 1.2) , 56.87 CO GPM (Limit is 15).  The car also won't rev over 4000 RPM and acts as if it has a governor on when it hits that RPM, it will shift gears just fine when you don't have the pedal pressed down too hard.

It started when I left a parking lot and went over a dip in the road a little fast and I heard the bottom of the car scrape.  Since then the engine sounds much louder than usual and the RPM problem started.  It also feels as if it has lower power than before. There is no check engine light. (It came on a month before the problems and I replaced the air intake tube that was cracked and it went away but hasn't returned.)

I'm assuming these are related but would rather try and figure out the problem myself and fix it rather than take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the catalytic converter for proper function?

Answer (score 0):

Check your exhaust system.  It sounds as though the bump you scraped may have "pinched" or damaged in some other way your exhaust.  The exhaust hands under the car and is one of the most vulnerable components to damage when a car "grounds out" or beaches.

A restriction in the exhaust would cause the poor running you describe.  However, it may be that the oxygen sensor in the exhaust is either damaged or getting a false reading due to exhaust damage which is causing it to meter out the wrong amount of fuel.

First thing I'd do personally is put the car on ramps or hold it securely on axle stand (don't go underneath with just a jack supporting the car) and make a really thorough inspection of the exhaust.  Look for visual damage and then, with the engine running (in a well ventilated area) listen for signs of gas escaping through the joins of the system.

Good luck.